# Sorting a Vector by ascending order

Tags: r

I have a vector like this -

```
MyVector <- c("2:3", "11:6", "9:10")
```

I am going to call this as x:y. I want to sort the values of x in ascending order.

So my sorted vector needs to look like,

```
"2:3", "9:10", "11:6"
```

and after sorting, I would like to output the values of Y in a different vector

FinalVector will look like:

```
"3", "10", "6"
```

Comment: If the fact that what you are storing in your vectors are numbers matters, then I highly suggest using a list to store said vectors rather than storing them in characters.

Comment: `gsub(".*:", "", MyVector[order(as.numeric(gsub(":.*", "", MyVector)))])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MyVector <- c("2:3", "11:6", "9:10")
gsub(".*:", "", MyVector[order(as.numeric(gsub(":.*", "", MyVector)))])
[1] "3"  "10" "6"
```

Explanation:

- `gsub(":.*", "", MyVector)` - Extract part before `:` (eg., `2`,  `11`, `9`)
- Turn them into numbers and get their order in original vector
- Extract values from original vector in specified order
- `gsub(".*:", "" ...)` - Delete part before `:`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
a <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(MyVector, ":")))
a[c(FALSE, TRUE)][order(a[c(TRUE, FALSE)])]

#[1]  3 10  6
```